# Can ping the openvpn server but can't ping another ping another client on the same VPN?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I've followed the following tutorial for setting up OPENVPN on Ubuntu 16.04 server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Then I created another client (client2) using steps 6 and from 11 to 13.
Two things had me confused:
- Although I added the push instruction on the server configuration file, the traffic on both machines isn't routed through the VPN.
- The mask looks odd (I might be mistaken as I'm new to this) 
Relative output in ifconfig:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:209 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1092 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:39180 (39.1 KB)
```

I can ping the server (ip: 10.8.0.1), but not the other machine.
Client1: Ubuntu16.04, ip: 10.8.0.5
Client2: Windows 7  , ip: 10.8.0.10

My goal is to have one of the machines use services using the LAN ip address of the other machine.
Edit:
I fixed the first problem of routing all traffic, and uncommented the line

```
client-to-client
```

So that clients would be able to see each other, but can't ping the other clients

Edit:
server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

route -n :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         80.211.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
80.211.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Please post your settings. And remove the default comments from the file. `grep -v ^# openvpn.conf | grep -v ^$` will remove blank lines and comments...

Comment: @ThoriumBR Added server.conf

Comment: I guess the routing entry is missing. Can you post your routes too?

Comment: @ThoriumBR added routing

Comment: Add `topology subnet` to your server, and restart.